# Google Tag Manager include that passes mod-security rules in Apache

Tags: apache, iframe, google-tag-manager, mod-security

I've been looking into using Google Tag Manager on my website, but I've failed at the first hurdle due to the default Google include code being blocked by the mod-security installation on my server:

Standard GTM include code:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXXX"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Response from mod-security:

```
WARNING:    Possibly malicious iframe tag in output
Message:    Outbound Anomaly Score Exceeded (score 15): Possibly malicious iframe tag in output
```

The rules triggered are ids 981000 and 981001.

I can understand why mod-security might think an iframe with "display:none;visibility:hidden" could be possibly malicious, and removing the style attribute stops rule 981001 from triggering, but the request still fails because of rule 981000.

981000 seems to have a strong opinion about what the width and height attributes should be, but I've tried setting them to '1' and '10' to no avail :-(

Does anyone know how to format an iframe to fit this rule? or how to change the GTM include code so that it doesn't contain the iframe?

Thanks

PS: I know you *can* solve this problem by removing the whole **noscript** area, but I'm looking for a solution that doesn't alter the functionality of the include code.

PPS: this is the pattern that rule 981000 is matching, I can understand about half of it before my brain explodes in a cloud of nested capture groups ;-)

```
Pattern match "<\W*iframe[^>]+?\b(?:width|height)\b\W*?=\W*?["']?[^"'1-9]*?(?:(?:20|1?\d(?:\.\d*)?)(?![\d%.])|[0-3](?:\.\d*)?%)"
```

Answer (score 10):

After a lot of experimentation - I found the following code works:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXXX"
height="21" width="21" class ="noDisplay"></iframe></noscript>
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

It seems rule 981000 will fire for any iframe that is less than 21 pixels or 3% in width or height. Moving the visibility and display style information to an external stylesheet prevented rule 981001 from firing.

```
.noDisplay {
display:none;
visibility:hidden;
}
```

The code now passes mod security and includes GTM in the page in (pretty much) the way Google intended.

I hope that helps someone else struggling with the same problem :-)

Answer (score 5):

Great solution, thanks for posting the answer! Much needed help at a tight timeline!

The new recommended GTM implementation recommends splitting the code into two sections, so for the sake of everyone's benefit, here is how I modified the above answer to comply with the preferred implementation. It also prevents the 403 Forbidden Error.

To be added as high in the `<head>` as possible:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

To be added as high in the `<body>` as possible:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src=""https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXXX""
height=""21"" width=""21"" class =""noDisplay""></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

To be added in an external stylesheet (usually style.css):

```
.noDisplay {display:none;visibility:hidden;}
```

All credits to @underscorePez for the original solution that lead me to the above!